# Pulling Yields Data from investpy package

Tags: python

I'm interested in using the `investpy` python package to pull yield curve data from the investing.com website (specifically interested in the South African yields at https://za.investing.com/rates-bonds/south-africa-government-bonds in order to manually construct a yield curve).

The package's documentation gives some examples of how to pull indices or stock data such as below, however there's no information on what arguments to pass through in order to pull interest rates/yields data. Looking for a solution on how to tweak the code below in order to pull a historical series for each of the yield maturities into a dataframe

```
import investpy

df = investpy.get_stock_historical_data(stock='AAPL',
                                        country='United States',
                                        from_date='01/01/2010',
                                        to_date='01/01/2020')
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download bond yield data using `investpy`, try the following code tweaked specifically for your needs

```
import investpy
data = investpy.bonds.get_bond_historical_data(bond='South Africa 2Y',
                                               from_date='01/01/2019',
                                               to_date='31/12/2019')
data[:10]
```

Please note country codes for bonds related to United States and UK are 'U.S.' and 'U.K.' respectively.